# What is the difference between RETURNS `SETOF integer` and RETURNS TABLE(name int)`?

Tags: postgresql, functions, set-returning-functions, c

Given the two definitions below, is there any difference?

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION foo(OUT foobar int4)
RETURNS SETOF int4
AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME', 'foo'
LANGUAGE C STRICT VOLATILE;
```

And,

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION foo()
RETURNS TABLE(foobar int4)
AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME', 'foo'
LANGUAGE C STRICT VOLATILE;
```

That is to say is there a difference between the *"Result data type"* as displayed with `\df` between

- `TABLE(foobar integer)`
- and, `SETOF interger` where the `Argument data types` includes `OUT foobar integer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The docs say this on `CREATE FUNCTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html)

> The name of an output column in the `RETURNS TABLE` syntax. This is effectively another way of declaring a named `OUT` parameter, except that `RETURNS TABLE` also implies `RETURNS SETOF`.